# Difference between char[] and char * in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

What is the difference between char[] s and char * s in C?
I understand that both create make 's' a pointer to the array of characters.
However,

```
char s[] = "hello";
s[3] = 'a';
printf("\n%s\n", s);
```

prints `helao`,while

```
char * s = "hello";
s[3] = 'a';
printf("\n%s\n", s);
```

gives me a segmentation fault. Why is there such a difference?
I'm using gcc on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using `char s[] = "hello";`, the char array is created in the scope of the current function, hence the memory is allocated on the stack when entering the function.

When using `char *s = "hello";`, `s` is a pointer to a constant string which the compiler saves in a block of memory of the program which is blocked for write-access, hence the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 5):

In both cases, a constant string of characters `"hello\0"` is allocated in a read-only section of the executable image.

In the case of `char* s="hello"`, the variable `s` is set to point to the location of that string in memory every time the function is called, so it can be used for read operations (`c = s[i]`), but not for write operations (`s[i] = c`).

In the case of `char s[]="hello"`, the array `s` is allocated on the stack and filled with the contents of that string every time the function is called, so it can be used for read operations (`c = s[i]`) and for write operations (`s[i] = c`).

Answer (score 0):

One is a pointer the other is an array.

An array defines data that stays in the current scope stack space.

A pointer defines a memory address that is in the current scope stack space, but which references memory from the heap.